# Swift 4- http request Post to login in website

Tags: swift, swift4, xcode9, xcode10

I'm searching about how to send some data to a website. For example, I want to send username and password to a website and I want to check if the login is successful or not. I searched a lot but I don't know how to do it.

If anyone has a background in HTTP request POST in Swift, I hope you can help me to send this data to a  website using Swift 4.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login"

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get).authenticate(user: "username", password: "pwd").responseJSON
    }
}
```

Comment: Login feature is sort of unique for each site, so first, you need to know how login works for the site.

Comment: i need only instagram if you know how and thanks for your comment

Comment: You should better update your question and tag, to include `instagram`. Many people know something about instagram. Though, I'm afraid usual apps would not use login feature. Anyway you need to be more specific, what you really want to do after login?

Comment: If you want to login to instagram from your app, you should have a look into the [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). Doing the regular login that a user normally goes through will likely not succeed because they likely have methods in place to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have use with post method i am giving you example code like below

```
func loginAPI(){
    let params = ["username": "your username","password": "your password"]
     Alamofire.request("ApiURL", method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON
     {
             response in
             print(response)

     }
}
```

Please check my code i hope it will help you